# ValueError: time data '2021-07-28 10:27:51,834' does not match format '&Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'

Tags: python, string, sorting, time

Can please anyone look around what is wrong with time format here?

Getting :

## ValueError: time data '2021-07-28 10:27:51,834' does not match format '&Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'

Using this right here:

```
import re
from time import strptime

time_short = re.compile(r"(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)")
t_fmt = '&Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'
with open(r'output\output.txt', 'r+') as file:
   lines = file.readlines()
   for i in sorted(lines, key=lambda i: strptime(time_short.search(i).group(1), t_fmt)):
      print(i)
```

File will look like:

```
2021-07-28 10:27:49,869 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:49,881 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:51,834 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following>
```

Maybe any idea? Thanks for any advice!

---

Edited 09/08/2021

---

Thanks very much for help, It was so dully asking this. Sorry, for the trouble.
But there is one more issue which has appeared after time format had been corrected.

```
import re
from time import strptime

time_short = re.compile(r"(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)")
t_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'
with open(r'output\output.txt', 'r+') as file:
   lines = file.readlines()
   for i in sorted(lines, key=lambda i: strptime(time_short.search(i).group(1), t_fmt)):
      print(i)
```

But I'm still getting unsorted data like:

```
2021-07-28 10:27:51,834 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following>
2021-07-28 10:27:49,869 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following>
2021-07-28 10:27:49,881 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT<xml code following></xml code following>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo in your code.
Just change

`t_fmt = '&Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'`

to

`t_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'`

When I run the code, the sorting seems to work but not with the microseconds. Please keep in mind, that **time.strptime** does not work with microseconds, you'll have to use **datetime.strptime** instead.

You can try it here:
https://www.online-python.com/5LZhoAljfR

```
import re
from time import strptime
from datetime import datetime

time_short = re.compile(r"(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)")
t_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'

lines=[
"2021-07-28 10:20:30,100 aaa>",
"2021-07-28 10:21:30,200 bbb>",
"2021-07-28 10:20:30,400 ccc>",
"2021-07-28 10:20:30,300 ddd>",
"2021-07-28 10:20:30,500 eee>"]

for i in sorted(lines, key=lambda i: datetime.strptime(time_short.search(i).group(1), t_fmt)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I know, question I've asked is directed to ValueError, but may be any idea, why sorting does not make a thing? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tested your code on my computer with python2 and python3 and the sorting works fine besides the issue with the microseconds mentioned in my edit

Comment: It works just fine with datetime library. Thanks so much! @Leonhard Triendl